# Fetching xml with curl on https

Tags: php, xml, curl, adobe-connect

So I made a login to site like this:

```
    $ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=username&password=password');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info= curl_getinfo($ch);
    echo 'passed' . $info['total_time'] . ' secconds ' . $info['url'] . '------ and http-code'. $info['http_code'];
    print curl_error($ch);
```

After I want to fetch XML of my meetings by this link https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings

I tried the following code:

```
$ch1 = curl_init('https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings');
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
    curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch1);
    $info1= curl_getinfo($ch1);
    echo 'passed' . $info1['total_time'] . ' secconds ' . $info1['url'] . '------ and http-code'. $info1['http_code'];
    print curl_error($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);
            curl_close($ch);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
    print_r($xml);
```

What can you advise me?

**Note**: i can see xml when i input this link on browser

**Structure**:

```
<results>
    <status code="ok"></status>
    <my-meetings>
    <meeting sco-id="1282590819" type="meeting" icon="meeting" permission-id="host" active-participants="0">
    <meeting sco-id="1282620938" type="meeting" icon="meeting" permission-id="host" active-participants="0">
  </my-meetings>

 </results>
```

**Output**:
like this for ex:

```
sample1aksamaimeet77842937.adobeconnect.com/sample1/2014-02-28T06:15:00.000-08:002014-02-28T07:15:00.000-08:00false01:00:00.000sample2meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/sample2/2014-02-28T06:15:00.000-08:002014-02-28T07:15:00.000-08:00false01:00:00.000
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, I edited question.You can see structure and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
```

Also:

```
$data = curl_exec($ch1); // after this line
var_dump(htmlentities($data)); // add this one
```

to see what's the output. It'll give you a starting point to debug.

**UPDATE**

Add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies');
// repeat this for all $ch, $ch1, $ch2 and such where you need auth cookie available
```

to store the login information and reuse it in other requests. Your error shows your second request goes unauthenticated. So I assume first one sets a cookie for login unless you need to carry over a variable returned by the first login sequence.

**AND** remove the `\` in `password\`. Your password has an extra character that should not be there!

**Working code**:

```
// Login.
$ch = curl_init('https://emea2cps.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=login&login=username&password=password');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);

// Query.
$ch = curl_init('https://meet77842937.adobeconnect.com/api/xml?action=report-my-meetings');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__.'/cookies');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__.'/cookies');
$data = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($data);
curl_close($ch);
```

Read it. It's clear enough.

Comment: **string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<results><status code="no-access" subcode="no-login"/></results>' (length=104)** this message is given for **var_dump**, but I made successful login to account in first part of code

Comment: You are not logged in. If the login works with cookies, you need a `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to store the login data.

Comment: so I stored the cookie to some file, how to use it after fetch xml?

Comment: Updated the answer. Read it and tell me if you have other questions. To reuse them you need to do the `curl_setopt($, COOKIE_*)` on each handle where you need them.

Comment: @nurgasemetey I also removed your username and password from code and your question.